# NodeJS Everyauth multiple redirect

Tags: facebook, node.js, oauth-2.0, everyauth

I am using Everyauth + Express + NodeJS to allow users to log into Facebook. I would like to re-direct them to the page that they logged-in from - is there any way I can get the everyauth.facebook configuration to support multiple redirect urls?

thanks.

Comment: Ah. This has been answered on the github issues: https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/issues/12 https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/issues/41